# C# How to Navigate with post data using the geckofx browser?

Tags: visual-studio, post, gecko, geckofx, navigateurl

I'm using C# with Visual Studio 2013, working with the geckofx browser, and I need to Navigate  using POST. The Navigate method is telling me I need a MimeInputStream, which is intuitive to use. The problem I'm facing with that is how to initialize it? MimeInputStream doesn't have a constructor. I found that the following code compiles, except the part where it can't cast the GeckoMIMEInputStream into a MimeInputStream like that. My code is:

```
string dataString = string.Format("username={0}&pwd={1}, Username, Password);

GeckoMIMEInputStream postData = new GeckoMIMEInputStream();
postData.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
postData.AddContentLength = true;
postData.SetData(dataString);

myGeckoFXBrowser.Navigate("javascript:void(document.getElementById('formname').submit())", GeckoLoadFlags.ReplaceHistory, null, postData);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Tom, that sent me to the right direction; here is my production code:

```
protected void NavigateWithPostData(string URLToGoTo, string POSTData)
{
    var postData = MimeInputStream.Create();
    postData.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    postData.AddContentLength = true;
    postData.SetData(POSTData);

    mainBrowser.Navigate(URLToGoTo, GeckoLoadFlags.BypassCache, mainBrowser.Url.AbsoluteUri, postData);
}
```

Then use it like:

```
    string dataString = string.Format("SMNTH={0}&SDAY={1}&SYR={2}", workingDate.Month, workingDate.Day, workingDate.Year);

    NavigateWithPostData("http://<yourapp>", dataString);
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't actually tried this, but:

```
var postData = MimeInputStream.Create();
postData.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
postData.AddContentLength = true;
postData.SetData(dataString);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a long time, but I am experiencing the same issue :

var postData = MimeInputStream.Create();

I have a classic "system.NullReferenceException", no constructor for MimeInputStream as said before...